# Meaning of のだろう?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-の, questions

I'm not sure when should I use particle の in front of だろう/でしょう?
Is のだろう used when the speaker wonders about something to himself?

For example, what would be the translation of these sentences:

> 日本は、これからますます高齢化が進むだろう。
> It seems that lately the aging in Japan is increasing.
>
> 最近、デパートの売り上げが伸びている。景気が回復しているのだろう。
> Store's sales increased. I wonder if the business is recovering?
>
> 何をするのだろうか。
> What could I do?

Comment: When you want to turn a verb into a noun.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I don't think that's relevant.

Answer (score 13):

When a verb is directly marked by だろう／でしょう, there are three meanings:

> 行くだろう
>   "It will (probably) go." (downwards tone throughout)
>   "It's going, isn't it?" (upwards during 行く, then downstep)
>   "I wonder if it will go." (neutral tone throughout)

While if it's marked by （ん／の）＋（だろう／でしょう）, it's like before, but the first option is strengthened a little:

> 行くのだろう
>   "I'm sure it will go." (downwards tone throughout)
>   "It's going, isn't it?" (upwards during 行くの, then downstep)
>   "I wonder if it it will go." (neutral tone throughout)

In writing, when there isn't a の, the 3rd option (rhetorical question) isn't quite as likely, but in speech they are all disambiguated quite well. I'm not sure if that's a personal quirk of my Japanese or not.